# Toggle All AutoCorrect in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to disable/re-enable auto-correct in Microsoft Word without un-checking/checking every feature in the File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options... menu. Having to remember which ones I un-checked is unacceptable. Ideally there would be a hotkey which turns off auto-correct during a session, or for some document. Red underlines when I'm writing shell scripts and other technical documents is also annoying and I'd like to toggle that feature off as well.

How to disable all auto-correct and spell-check and re-enable without toggling every option?

Comment: I couldn't find a toggle, but you can add the AutoCorrect Options menu to your quick access toolbar.